# Ember silently failing on Ubuntu 14

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ember-cli

I installed ember on my ubuntu and now when I use the ember command eg:
ember new asdfasdf

nothing happens, it fails silently. I have tried doing this with sudo. I cant seem to get the version of my node or ember either everything fails silently.

Help would be greatly appreciated!!
Thanks in advance

```
arie@arie-UX32VD:~$ sudo npm install -g ember-cli
[sudo] password for arie: 

> ws@0.5.0 install /usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/testem/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory '/usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/testem/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node: Finished
  COPY Release/bufferutil.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node: Finished
  COPY Release/validation.node
make: Leaving directory '/usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/testem/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/build'

> ws@0.4.31 install /usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/testem/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory '/usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/testem/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node: Finished
  COPY Release/bufferutil.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node: Finished
  COPY Release/validation.node
make: Leaving directory '/usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/testem/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'
/usr/bin/ember -> /usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember
ember-cli@0.2.3 /usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli
├── broccoli-unwatched-tree@0.1.1
├── pleasant-progress@1.0.2
├── is-git-url@0.2.0
├── abbrev@1.0.5
├── ember-cli-copy-dereference@1.0.0
├── promise-map-series@0.2.1
├── js-string-escape@1.0.0
├── walk-sync@0.1.3
├── broccoli-merge-trees@0.2.1
├── exit@0.1.2
├── semver@4.3.3
├── strip-ansi@2.0.1 (ansi-regex@1.1.1)
├── temp@0.8.1 (rimraf@2.2.8)
├── rsvp@3.0.18
├── symlink-or-copy@1.0.1 (copy-dereference@1.0.0)
├── broccoli-sane-watcher@1.0.2 (broccoli-slow-trees@1.1.0)
├── debug@2.1.3 (ms@0.7.0)
├── http-proxy@1.11.0 (requires-port@0.0.0, eventemitter3@0.1.6)
├── core-object@0.0.2 (lodash-node@2.4.1)
├── broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers@0.2.6 (mkdirp@0.3.5, glob@4.0.4)
├── broccoli-funnel@0.2.2 (mkdirp@0.5.0, minimatch@2.0.4)
├── sane@1.0.3 (watch@0.10.0, minimatch@0.2.14, fb-watchman@0.0.0, walker@1.0.6)
├── rimraf@2.3.2 (glob@4.5.3)
├── yam@0.0.18 (findup@0.1.5, fs-extra@0.16.5, lodash.merge@3.2.0)
├── broccoli-writer@0.1.1 (quick-temp@0.1.2)
├── ember-router-generator@0.3.3 (recast@0.9.18)
├── broccoli-filter@0.1.12 (mkdirp@0.3.5, quick-temp@0.1.2)
├── markdown-it@4.0.3 (linkify-it@1.0.1, uc.micro@1.0.0, mdurl@1.0.0, entities@1.1.1, argparse@1.0.2)
├── broccoli-es3-safe-recast@2.0.0 (es3-safe-recast@2.0.1)
├── broccoli-es6modules@0.5.1 (mkdirp@0.5.0, esperanto@0.6.29, broccoli-caching-writer@0.5.3)
├── markdown-it-terminal@0.0.2 (ansi-styles@2.0.1, cli-table@0.3.1, cardinal@0.5.0, lodash-node@3.7.0)
├── broccoli-sourcemap-concat@0.4.4 (mkdirp@0.5.0, combined-stream@0.0.7, fast-sourcemap-concat@0.2.4, lodash-node@2.4.1, broccoli-caching-writer@0.5.3)
├── broccoli-caching-writer@0.5.5 (core-object@0.0.3, quick-temp@0.1.2, lodash-node@2.4.1)
└── testem@0.8.0 (growl@1.8.1, styled_string@0.0.1, did_it_work@0.0.6, consolidate@0.11.0, charm@1.0.0, xmldom@0.1.19, async@0.9.0, mustache@1.2.0, cross-spawn@0.2.9, colors@1.0.3, commander@2.8.0, mkdirp@0.5.0, glob@4.5.3, backbone@1.1.2, fileset@0.1.5, fireworm@0.6.6, express@4.12.3, npmlog@1.2.0, js-yaml@3.2.7, tap@0.6.0, socket.io@1.3.5)
arie@arie-UX32VD:~$ ember
arie@arie-UX32VD:~$ ember new asdf
arie@arie-UX32VD:~$ ls
Desktop    Dropbox           Music          Pictures   Videos
Documents  examples.desktop  node_modules   Public
Downloads  fontconfig        npm-debug.log  Templates
arie@arie-UX32VD:~$ 
arie@arie-UX32VD:~$ 
arie@arie-UX32VD:~$ 
arie@arie-UX32VD:~$
```

Comment: Describe the steps that you followed to install everything.

Comment: I already had rails working when I started installing ember, I wanted to make an ember-rails app using the ember-cli so I installed node "sudo apt-get install node" and I installed npm and using npm I attempted to install ember using: sudo npm install -g ember-cli

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you if you do not describe **what you did**. Your previous comment serves no purpose.

Comment: I added to my question, does that help? Do you see how it silently fails? To install it I just got node and ember

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not install node as sudo, you can google the reasonings.

To quickly get you started with ember do this:

```
# installs nvm (node version manager)
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.24.1/install.sh | bash
# installs node
nvm install 0.12
npm install -g ember-cli
ember new foobar
```

With what you had you would do:

```
sudo ember new foobar
```

and that is asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks my problem was in node, node wasn't installed before I guess? Even though I tried to get it with apt-get, why is it working now?

Comment: Now different users (you and root) have different versions of Node.